# Better way to check config to make sure each rules are unique

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary of configs (defined by the user as settings for a Django app).

And I need to check the config to make sure it fits the rules.

The rule is very simple. The 'range' within each option must be unique.

## sample settings

```
breakpoints = {
    'small': {
        'verbose_name': _('Small screens'),
        'min_width': None,
        'max_width': 640,
    },
    'medium': {
        'verbose_name': _('Medium screens'),
        'min_width': 641,
        'max_width': 1024,
    },
    'large': {
        'verbose_name': _('Large screens'),
        'min_width': 1025,
        'max_width': 1440,
    },
    'xlarge': {
        'verbose_name': _('XLarge screens'),
        'min_width': 1441,
        'max_width': 1920,
    },
    'xxlarge': {
        'verbose_name': _('XXLarge screens'),
        'min_width': 1921,
        'max_width': None,
    }
}
```

Here's what Ive come with so far. It works but don't seem very pythonic.

```
for alias, config in breakpoints.items():
    for alias2, config2 in breakpoints.items():
        if not alias2 is alias:
            msg = error_msg % (alias, 'breakpoint clashes with %s breakpoint' % alias2)
            for attr in ('min_width', 'max_width', ):
                if config[attr] is not None:
                    if (config2['min_width'] and config2['max_width']) and \
                            (config2['min_width'] <= config[attr] <= config2['max_width']):
                        raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg)
                    elif (config2['min_width'] and not config2['max_width']) and \
                            (config2['min_width'] < config[attr]):
                        raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg)
                    elif (config2['max_width'] and not config2['min_width']) and \
                            (config2['max_width'] > config[attr]):
                        raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg)
```

Is there a better way I can solve this?

Comment: Yes, seeing as you have a working solution, I won't go into effort on this, but your sample looks like it can be serialized into a somewhat complex model and you can then use the model to work on it.

Comment: reading my answer and that of @tdelaney, I see that it is not clear from your post whether you want ranges to be different or disjoint. For instance: 0-100 and 50-200 are different but are not disjoint.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear on the requirements, each config has to be a `disjoint` set

Comment: Ok, then @tdelaney's answer is closer to what you want.

Comment: To me, this is crying for a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy to scan for overlapping ranges if you sort the dataset first. 'None' appears to be used for different things in different places (as min its zero) as max its "greater than anything" - but that's harder to compare. If you have a real maximum, it makes the sorting a bit easier.

(edit: scan for max because there is no known maximum)

```
MAX = max(val.get('max_width', 0) for val in breakpoints.itervalues()) + 1
# sort by min/max
items = sorted(
    (data['min_width'] or 0, data['max_width'] or MAX, name) 
    for name, data in breakpoints.iteritems())
# check if any range overlaps the next higher item
for i in range(len(items)-1):
    if items[i][0] > items[i][1]:
        print "range is incorrect for", items[i][1]
    elif items[i][1] >= items[i+1][0]:
        print items[i+1][2], 'overlaps'
```

Comment: Maximum can be anything. Minimum value can be assummed to be zero if none is given

Comment: Since there is no max, you can calculate from existing data.

Comment: you have data, name flipped in the creation of items.

Answer (score 0):

You can get from that a dict with the ranges as pairs:

```
ranges = { 'small': (None, 640), 'medium': (641, 1024), ...}
```

and then check, say, that `len(set(ranges.values())) == len(ranges)`
EDIT: this works if the requirement is for ranges to be different. See @tdelaney's answer for disjoint ranges.